# Accessing vertices of a rendered object in 3.js

Tags: three.js

I'm new to `three.js` and I am working on a project that helps in editing 3D objects. I have used the `OBJLoader` to load an object in `.obj` format and render it. Now I want to access the vertices of the rendered object.

Can you please help me in doing this one?

Comment: added code formatting to code specific blocks in question

Answer (score 0):

Every three.js Geometry instance has a .verticies array. See the [docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry).
Output your OBJLaoder object to the javasccript console of your browser and you should be able to find the verticies.
It would help if you posted some code.

Comment: I'm not able to see any vertices.... the object is just displayed as [object Object].

Comment: use the console in developer tools. To output to it `console.log('test');`

Answer (score 0):

```
loader.load( 'obj/test/testCube.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            window.alert("CHILD"+child.geometry.vertices);
            child.material.map = texture;
        }
    }
});
```